# 301 Redirect index.php?dir= to a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permanent

I want to redirect the following

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=Dir1
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=Dir1/Dir2
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/folder/Dir1
http://www.example.com/folder/Dir1/Dir2
```

I want to "301 Redirect" it NOT "Rewrite" i.e I want the "index.php?dir=" link to 301 redirect to folder structure.
Please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your DocumentRoot `.htaccess`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^  folder/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)/? folder/index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question (or I haven't explained in detail). I just want the "index.php?dir=" to go away. The dir1/dir2 was just an example! Anyways your code goes into a redirection loop.

Comment: @user1170540 try now. Observe the order or rewrite rule.

Comment: Still redirection loop! Why are you suggesting 'folder/index.php?dir=Dir1/Dir2' above! Dir1 and Dir2 is just a virtual example folder. All I want is everything after /index.php?dir= to be redirected to /

Comment: @user1170540 my bad, I did a oversight. Hadn't noticed `dir=Dir1/Dir2` in my rule. Try now.

Comment: Still redirection loop! :( Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1170540 Am a bit sleepy. Gimme a min.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more I am writing xyz.com/folder/index.php?dir=Blah and intend it to redirect it to xyz.com/folder/Blah

Comment: @user1170540 check the above. It should definitely work (if it does not conflict with any other rewrites you have in folder `folder`)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^folder/index\.php$  folder/%1 [L,R=302]
```

change to 301 once working.

Comment: This doesn't works at all! The index.php?dir= remains in the URL!